# Correct syntax for rescue and next in a each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, rescue

I have a fairly straightforward if else statement in a controller as follows:

```
if citation_array.blank?
  flash.now[:error] = "There was a problem saving the publications selected!"
  @user = current_user
  render  'pubmed_search'
else
  citation_array.each do |user_publication|
    begin
      publication = Publication.new
      render_publication(user_publication)
      publication.citation = user_publication
      publication.user_id  = current_user.id
      publication.title = @title
      publication.authors = @authors
      publication.journal = @journal
      publication.year = @year
      publication.volume = @volume
      publication.pages  = @pages
      if publication.save
        next
      end
    rescue
      next
    end
  end

  @user = current_user
  redirect_to current_user
  return false
end
```

It is served an array of id's in citation_array and if there are values present it loops throught them saving each publication found by the id's in the array. The render_publication method instantiates the instance variables so don't be concerned with that.

My issue is this. Very rarely an id is fake or wrong and so this block fails at that point. I want to simple move on to the next id in the array and forget about the failed id. I don't even need to save an exception. I'm new to Ruby (coming from a PHP background).

I want to check if this syntax is correct. I am having trouble checking it in the rails console.

Comment: The syntax looks correct. You don't even need to add `next` after `rescue` statement.

Comment: What is the line that you expect triggering an exception? If you think about `save`, then keep in mind save will return `false` on failure, it will not raise a exception.

Comment: Right - that is very important to know. I was mainly looking to recover from a situation where it did not save. So in reality I should just have an"if publication.save....else....end" right?

Answer (score 4):

Syntax errors are easier to spot if the code is indented correctly.

```
if citation_array.blank?
  flash.now[:error] = "There was a problem saving the publications selected!"
  @user = current_user
  render  'pubmed_search'
else
  citation_array.each do |user_publication|
    begin
      publication = Publication.new
      render_publication(user_publication)
      publication.citation = user_publication
      publication.user_id  = current_user.id
      publication.title = @title
      publication.authors = @authors
      publication.journal = @journal
      publication.year = @year
      publication.volume = @volume
      publication.pages  = @pages
      if publication.save
        next
      end
    rescue
      next
    end
  end
  @user = current_user
  redirect_to current_user
  return false
end
```

The syntax seems correct. Though an easier way to find out would have been just to run the code.

Some things in the code are not necessary though. After cleaning up your code a bit, it would look something like this with the same functionality.

```
@user = current_user
if citation_array.blank?
  flash.now[:error] = 'There was a problem saving the publications selected!'
  render 'pubmed_search'
else
  citation_array.each do |user_publication|
    begin
      render_publication(user_publication)
      Publication.create!( # create! here so that if something does go wrong, then you're not just ignoring it, but you can log it in your rescue block.
        citation: user_publication,
        user_id: current_user.id,
        title: @title,
        authors: @authors,
        journal: @journal,
        year: @year,
        volume: @volume,
        pages: @pages
        # This hash should be extracted to a method.
      )
    rescue
      # Just doing nothing here is valid syntax, but you should at least log your error.
    end
  end
  redirect_to current_user
  false # This can most likely be omitted as well since not many places care about the return value of a controller action.
end
```

Comment: Using a bang version along with an empty block is non-sense. Just use `create` then and get rid of the whole begin/rescue block.

Comment: An empty rescue block is what the question requested. As you can see, I advised against that in my example.

Comment: If you don't use the bang version of create, you don't need it.

Comment: I do not know the contents of  `render_publication` and therefore cannot be sure it is not designed to raise an exception on a faulty or fake id.`create` without a bang will not fail indeed but it is bad practice to not check the return value of `save` and the lot.

Comment: Note: according to Ruby 2.7.1 https://ruby-doc.com/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html, the `begin` within loops and methods is unnecessary.

Answer (score -4):

Syntax for begin-rescue,

`begin
  your code...
rescue => e
 Rails.logger.debug 'Exception is #{e}'
end`

Comment: Correct, but not OP's original question, they wanted to know how to `rescue` (and execute `next`) within an iterator.